# How can i deploy ember cli index to s3 without sha

Tags: ember.js, deployment, amazon-s3, ember-cli

i'm using ember-cli-deploy and ember-deploy-s3-index.

Following [this article](http://kerrygallagher.co.uk/deploying-an-ember-cli-application-to-amazon-s3/) i managed to deploy the index to a bucket with static web hosting and another bucket holding the assets.

I want to automate (CI) the deploy process but there are two problems:

1. Each deploy adds an index file with a new name (test:b2907fa.html for example), and i need to manually change the index document to match the latest deploy in my s3 configuration.
2. I need to add permissions to the file on each deploy.

I would like to have a fixed name (override existing on deploy) for my index file, and that the file will have view permissions by default.

Is this possible? 
Thanks.

Comment: I managed to solve #2 by adding bucket policy

Comment: Do not fingerprint index.html file.

Comment: you don't need to change index file name , as index.html will always represent your activated revision, or current.
source: https://github.com/Kerry350/ember-deploy-s3-index#file-representation

Comment: How can this work? There is no such file called index.html in the bucket..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out you don't need to change the index document.

After deploy you need to run ember:deploy:activate --revision test:b2907fa --environment production and it will change it in the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative with no add-ons/dependencies:

Deploying an ember cli app is as simple as syncing the contents of the `dist/` folder to your server (after building with `--production` flag) These files can then be statically served

Here is a script I wrote to automate my deploy process:

```
printf "** Depoying application**\n"
cd ~/Desktop/Project/ember_test/censored

printf "\n** Building static files **\n"
ember build --environment=production

printf "\n** Synchronizing distribution folder to frontend.censored.co.za **\n"
rsync -rv ~/Desktop/Project/ember_test/censored/dist frontend@frontend.censored.co.za:/var/www/html/censored --exclude ".*/" --exclude ".*" --delete

printf "\n** Removing production build from local repository **\n"
rm -rv ~/Desktop/Project/ember_test/censored/dist/*

printf "\n** Deployment done. **\n"
```

This deploys to a linux server where you want to deploy to s3

So instead of my 3rd command (`rsync`) you would use [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to put your folder into s3 (It would probably be a `s3cmd put` command)

Comment: Thanks, but i really want to use ember deploy for this.